# An event-log data-set for evaluating a filtering system?

Tags: time-series, dataset

For my research, I am working on an event filtering/matching system that considers each event to be a set of key-value pairs (e.g. "action=logon", "user=john.doe").

I would like to evaluate its validity, but I have been unable to find a public data-set with my requirements:

- It has to be a time series of samples with a consistent internal structure.
- It should be sizable - at least several millions of records/events.
- It has to be pre-classified to a number of categories/use-cases. A mere classification into e.g. normal/abnormal is not enough. Alternatively, I could also use a set with a domain-specific tool that can perform this classification accurately.

  There are several data sets (e.g. web server logs) around, but I have yet to find one that satisfies this requirement; I need to be able both to train my system and evaluate its performance using *an accurate golden standard*.
- I would like the categories to be conceptual equals e.g. various bank transaction types. I am currently using the [KDD99](http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup99.html) data-set, but it is too focused on anomaly detection; while it does have separate anomaly classes, all "normal" events are lumped into the same category...

Is there a data-set somewhere that I could use? Preferably something that has already been peer-reviewed to a degree?

As an alternative, is there a standard tool or other way to *generate* such a data-set? I have considered setting up e.g. a Web application and hammering at it with a load tester, or even using a generic simulation tool, but I believe that none of these approaches would really stand to peer review, which would compromise the evaluation itself.

Comment: How did that go? it's been 6.5 years so I guess you figured it out? :)